# Can SDL sprites be drawn without SDL_Image?

Tags: c, sdl, game-development

Say I wanted to make a game where the graphics were just drawing pixels with SDL_Surface in a 16 bit game visual, instead of loading images. Could this be done, and could it be more efficient than loading images?

Comment: It can be done, and no it will not be more efficent.

Comment: Would there be any benefits?

Comment: No there will not be any difference between a SDL_Surface you have drawn pixels to compared to one loaded from an image.